# How to pass options to handlebars.precompile?

Tags: handlebars.js

So I've got this code that is running fine (I'm using gulp not grunt for what it matters) :

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    map = require('vinyl-map');

gulp.task('test', function(){
return gulp.src(config.path.template+"/*.handlebars")   
        .pipe(map(function(contents) {
            return handlebars.precompile(contents.toString());
        }))

.pipe(rename({ extname: '.js' }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.template+"/test"))
});
```

Everything runs perfectly, the .js files generate in the good folder, but I need them to generate without the -s parameter. For an example, when I run `handlebars path/to/my/hbs.handlebars -f path/to/my/out/folder.js -s` (or `--simple`), the file generated is the same. But I need this command to run without the `-s` parameter, and I can't find a way to pass this argument in my gulpfile. I tried alot of things, in a String, in a Json, in an array, tried to go with `-s false`, with `simple false`, with `isSimple false` (something I found in handlebars code).

None of this is working and I really need to pass the -s parameter to false. I assume that I need to do something like :

```
[...]
return handlebars.precompile(contents.toString(), options);
[...]
```

But I can't find the proper syntax or way to use these options. And that is my problem.

PS : I use this instead of gulp-handlebars so that I can use the version of handlebars I want to use and not another.

***EDIT***

Searching in `handlebars.js` code, I just found that `options` is an object, but I can't find what he's filled with as I'm not a good javascript user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there's no such switch in the source.
Taken from the [precompiler source](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/precompiler.js) used from the command line tool:

```
      if (opts.simple) {
        output.push(Handlebars.precompile(data, options) + '\n');
      } else if (opts.partial) {
        if (opts.amd && (opts.templates.length == 1 && !fs.statSync(opts.templates[0]).isDirectory())) {
          output.push('return ');
        }
        output.push('Handlebars.partials[\'' + template + '\'] = template(' + Handlebars.precompile(data, options) + ');\n');
      } else {
        if (opts.amd && (opts.templates.length == 1 && !fs.statSync(opts.templates[0]).isDirectory())) {
          output.push('return ');
        }
        output.push('templates[\'' + template + '\'] = template(' + Handlebars.precompile(data, options) + ');\n');
      }
```

`opts` is what you passed in, another variable `options` is passed to `precompile`. The decoration is added by the command line tool.
There's a second block with closing brackets a few lines below in the script.
You best copy that source to your code or maybe access the `.cli` object in your gulp script.